# How to set default URL for new Chrome *windows*

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Note that this isn't a new tab or on startup question.

If Chrome creates a new window, I'd love to be able to have it always open a default URL, but then for new tabs, open a Google search page.

AFAICT, you can set:
- default URL for startup (this is great)
- default URL for tabs (great for the first tab in a window, but not subsequent tabs...)

Anyone know if there a deep setting where I could adjust this?

The use case is for my mother-in-law, who both uses webmail and has a tendency to close her windows. I've already set up all the buttons she'll need in her bookmarks bar, but the opportunity to reduce 1 more click would be great.

Comment: Firefox has an option not to close window even if last tab is closed. From which Ctrl+Shift+T can reopen last closed tab.

Answer (score 0):

I no enough reputation to comment.

I added here. What you mean is open in desktop then open the specific link?

You can either generate URL file (New > Shortcut > put your link), if default browser is Chrome.
Else your can [change you shortcut target](https://www.technipages.com/windows-open-website-with-specific-browser)